# Xampp phonebook app SQLite3 error on Mac Yosemite

Tags: php, macos, apache, sqlite, xampp

As shown in the image, [image: this image] I get the following error on the Phonebook app installed on XAMPP:

```
Warning: SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, no such table: users in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/phonebook.php on line 69

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchArray() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/phonebook.php on line 72
```

I am on a Mac Yosemite running a fresh install of XAMPP 5.5.19-0.
I imagine that the problem is that there is no SQLite3 installed in XAMPP.
How can I install that?

Comment: Please create a file called info.php instead of phonebook.php and at the same folder like phonebook.php with the following content:

<?php  phpinfo();

Call it in the browser and post the results.

Comment: @itinance https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17270607/XAMPP%20for%20OS%20X%205.5.19-0_files/phpinfo.html

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3-support seems to be installed correctly. The warning you're posting tells you "no such table: users". I guess, there is no valid sqlite3-database file located or loaded. 
Just have a look at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/phonebook.php around line 69 and search for the database file path and check if it is existing on your filesystem and can be accessed by php.